# Add all parents TreeItems nodes in a TreeView to a List

Tags: java, javafx

How to make an ArrayList (lets say `arrayListOfTreeitems`) with all only parents TreeItems childreens?
To make visible, lets supose one main TreeItem (lets say `treeItemNodeMain`) inside a TreeView:

```txt
treeItemNodeMain:
----------------
+Parent1
       -Child1.1
+Parent2
       -Child2.1
       +Parent2.2
              -Child2.2.1
+Parent3
       +Parent3.1
              -Child3.1.1
       +Parent3.2
       +Parent3.3
              -Child3.3.1
```

In a way to get:

```txt
arrayListOfTreeitems = {
  Parent1,
  Parent2, Parent2.2,
  Parent3.1, Parent3.3
}
```

Comment: Recursively traverse the tree and add nodes with non-empty child lists to the list.

Comment: I'm  working with big trees (20000 nodes)... it would to take some amount of time. There is no other way to do it only for only one specific selected TreeItem?

Comment: Just recursively search from the selected item.

Comment: Study: [Tree Traversal Algorithms: Theory And Practice In Java](https://medium.com/swlh/tree-traversal-algorithms-theory-and-practice-in-java-7e7d1fe9ed30)

Answer (score 0):

With a recursive method who check if a node isleaf or not . if is not leaf will add that item to arraylist . this is a one class javafx program . you can test it if you want .

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import javafx.application.Application;
    import javafx.scene.Scene;
    import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
    import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
    import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
    import javafx.stage.Stage;

    public class App extends Application {

    @Override

    public void start(Stage stage) {

    TreeItem<String> parent1 = new TreeItem<>("Parent 1");
    TreeItem<String> child11 = new TreeItem<>("Child 1.1");
    TreeItem<String> parent2 = new TreeItem<>("Parent 2");
    TreeItem<String> child21 = new TreeItem<>("Child 2.1");
    TreeItem<String> parent22 = new TreeItem<>("Parent 2.2");
    TreeItem<String> child221 = new TreeItem<>("Child 1.1");
    TreeItem<String> parent3 = new TreeItem<>("Parent 3");
    TreeItem<String> parent31 = new TreeItem<>("Parent 3.1");
    TreeItem<String> child311 = new TreeItem<>("Child 3.1.1");
    TreeItem<String> parent32 = new TreeItem<>("Parent 3.2");
    TreeItem<String> parent33 = new TreeItem<>("Parent 3.3");
    TreeItem<String> child331 = new TreeItem<>("Child 3.3.1");
    

    parent1.getChildren().add(child11);
    parent2.getChildren().addAll(child21, parent22);
    parent22.getChildren().add(child221);
    parent3.getChildren().addAll(parent31, parent32, parent33);
    parent31.getChildren().add(child311);
    parent33.getChildren().add(child331);
    TreeView<String> tree = new TreeView<>();
    tree.setRoot(new TreeItem<>("root"));
    tree.setShowRoot(false);
    tree.getRoot().getChildren().addAll(parent1, parent2, parent3);
    
    ArrayList<TreeItem> arraylistOfTreItems = new ArrayList();
    App.getParentsInTreeItem(tree.getRoot(), arraylistOfTreItems);
    
    arraylistOfTreItems.forEach(parent-> 
    System.out.println(parent.getValue()));
    
    
    

    Scene scene = new Scene(new Pane(tree), 640, 480);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
public static void getParentsInTreeItem(TreeItem<String> parent, ArrayList list){

    parent.getChildren().forEach(item->{
    if(!item.isLeaf())list.add(item);
    if(!item.getChildren().isEmpty())
        getParentsInTreeItem(item, list);});
    
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}}
```

[image: tree aap]

the output with all itemTrees in  the arraylist

```
Parent 1
Parent 2
Parent 2.2
Parent 3
Parent 3.1
Parent 3.3
```